# Subclassing QAbstractProxyModel, adding tree nodes that do not exist in the source model

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel

I am trying to implement a ProxyModel that takes a source Model that represents a flat, table like structure.
Then you can select one column of this model as a grouping value.
The proxy model should then create as many top nodes as there are distinct values of this column and sort the underlying rows into them.

But when doing this, is subclassing `QAbstractProxyModel` a viable option?
Since `mapToSource(const QModelIndex& proxyIndex)` will not always return a valid source index for a valid proxy index.

Does someone have a better solution, perhaps just using a `QAbstractItemModel` without the built in proxy functionality?

Comment: The set of articles about models may help you: http://lynxline.com/category/models/

Answer (score 1):

Here are two example projects which address this issue, for anyone's future reference.  (One of them is mine, I do not mean to spam, it just seems relevant.)

[GroupedItemsProxyModel](https://github.com/mpaperno/maxLibQt/blob/master/src/itemmodels/GroupedItemsProxyModel.cpp) ([doc](https://mpaperno.github.io/maxLibQt/class_grouped_items_proxy_model.html))
[QGroupingProxyModel](https://sourceforge.net/p/qadvanceditemviews/code/ci/default/tree/qaivlib/qgroupingproxymodel.cpp) ([doc](http://qadvanceditemviews.sourceforge.net/class_q_grouping_proxy_model.html))

*Edit (response to comment)*:  Both projects implement what, I believe, the question is asking about.  I think examining the source provides the best examples and would obviously be too long to paste it all here.  I've provided links directly to the source and to relevant documentation.

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a 
specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some 
sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.

Comment: Understood, thanks.  I've edited my post to hopefully better explain why I'm providing the links.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Sorry, understood this a little wrong. I never derived from abstract proxy model so I am not sure about that. However I would start using a QSortFilterProxyModel. It may happen that it has some functionality you do not need but this does not hurt. On the other hand implementing your on proxy model could hurt since it requires additional work and know-how.

If you should experience problems switching from the non-grouped structure to the grouped structure within the proxy model consider switching the model of the view (one showing grouped data, one showing original un-grouped data).

Comment: What I meant is to create a Model that takes any flat table model and encapsulate it in a way that represents a Tree where the top nodes are the values of a specifies column.
So that I do not have to create Tree models for all data that I want to display this way.